# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'login'

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot

I'm trying to import and delete "login" data from one file to a different file but it fails.

file1.py:

```
@Client.on_message(filters.command("a"))
async def fileone(cl: Client, msg: Message):

    login = await msg.reply("Hello")
```

to file2:

```
from file1 import fileone
# or from file1 import *

@Client.on_callback_query(filters.regex("send"))
async def seend():

    file1.login.delete()
```

error output:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'login'
```

Comment: `login` is a local variable that only exists within the scope of the function `fileone` you cannot access from another function let alone another module

Comment: `file1.py` has a function named `fileone` that has a local variable that you assign to and then ignore.